# How to use playerprefs to lock levels on player death?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 60 levels with buttons.
I want lock some levels with playerprefs when the player dies.

For example when player dies in level 5, lock levels 5 and level 4 and make them restart from level 3.

Comment: Welcome to so!.  Follow this post to see how to ask questions that are more likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example is:

```
public void OnLevelStart(int currentLevel)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Last level", currentLevel);
}

private int levelPenaltyOffset = 2;

public int GetLastLevel()
{
    int result = levelPenaltyOffset;
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Last level"))
    {
        result = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Last level")
    }
    return result;
}
```

You need to call OnLevelStart when level change to save new value. You will call GetLastLevel when you need to know last level of player. If playerprefs have no values (user not started any level yet) method return 2 (you want to lock two levels from last). So you can use it like this:

```
int levelToLoad = GetLastLevel() - levelPenaltyOffset;
```

In this case if player not started yet you will get level with number 0.

Comment: may be you try to give more information? Show some code, or show some errors, or explaine what you mean "not working" about?

Comment: Sorry it is working now hhhh  thank you again man I am really appreciate it :D